# AWS Cognito: Identity Pool Facebook Integration

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I'm working on a cordova app and using aws cognito user pool and identity pool to authenticate users and access resources in AWS such as lambda, RDS etc.

With a simple signup using email and password, cognito identity pool has been working fine. However now I am trying to integrate facebook login. I can get facebook login using cordova facebook plugin and can get aws credentials using the facebook access token. But the problem is that a facebook user doesnt get created in cognito user pool.

P.S. I'm using `aws-cognito-identity-sdk` library from aws in my cordova app.

Is there any working example and/or documentation regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps given in the bellow documentation to integrate your federated identity pool with a cognito pool.

Find the "Configuring Your Identity Pool Using the AWS Management Console" section to follow the steps from  Amazon Cognito console.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html